# Change the Order of an Array of HashMaps based on Objects in the HashMap

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`.

Is there a way to change the order of the array of HashMaps? For example, if the String "firstName" is inside the HashMap, can I sort my ArrayList of HashMaps by that value? Just to be clear, I do not need to order keys and objects inside HashMaps. I need order HashMaps inside Arraylist.

What is a best way?

i tried to do from examples:

```
class MapComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>
{
    private final String key;

    public MapComparator(String key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> first,
            HashMap<String, String> second)
    {
        // TODO: Null checking, both for maps and values
         String firstName1 = first.get(key);
            String firstName2 = second.get(key);
            if(firstName1 == null)
                if(firstName2 == null)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return -1; // treat null as less than any non-null
            else
                if(firstName2 == null)
                    return 1; // treat null as less than any non-null
                else
                    return firstName1.compareTo(firstName2);

    }
}
```

and using:

```
                Log.e(THIS_FILE, "before ->" + addedRows);
                Collections.sort(addedRows, new MapComparator("name"));
                Log.e(THIS_FILE, "after ->" + addedRows);
```

and nothing sorted (to be sure i renamed one contact to start by letter a, hashmap with name=as ice:) must be first):

```
> E/ContactsActivity(23571): before ->[{type=, contactID=4, name=Office
> O}, {type=, contactID=2912, name=Test Text Last}, {type=,
> contactID=2915, name=as ife:) Eng}, {type=, contactID=2914,
> name=life:) Rus}, {type=, contactID=2913, name=life:) Ukr}, {type=,
> contactID=2897, name=дима куплеватскиц}] E/ContactsActivity(23571):
> after ->[{type=, contactID=4, name=Office O}, {type=, contactID=2912,
> name=Test Text Last}, {type=, contactID=2915, name=as ife:) Eng},
> {type=, contactID=2914, name=life:) Rus}, {type=, contactID=2913,
> name=life:) Ukr}, {type=, contactID=2897, name=дима куплеватскиц}]
```

Comment: actually this is a more Java answer than Android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369573/how-sort-an-arraylist-of-hashmaps-holding-several-key-value-pairs-each

Comment: `HashMap`s are unordered.  Try a `TreeMap` instead.

Comment: if you have any issue in using `TreeMap` then  see this post for [how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Comment: @Παύλος i don't understand, why u put minuses to question without understanding, what is inside. You example about "duplicated" doesn't work. Thank you for understanding and i hope minused will go down

Comment: I wasnt the one to add a minus in your question. Think before you say something

Comment: sorry :( i just was surprised, why community don't like question, it's a good question and i was investigate problem before make post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
java.util.Collections.sort
(
    list,
    new java.util.Comparator<Map<String,String>>()
    {
        public int compare(Map<String,String> map1, Map<String,String> map2)
        {
            String firstName1 = map1.get("firstName");
            String firstName2 = map2.get("firstName");
            if(firstName1 == null)
                if(firstName2 == null)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return -1; // treat null as less than any non-null
            else
                if(firstName2 == null)
                    return 1; // treat null as less than any non-null
                else
                    return firstName1.compareTo(firstName2);
        }
    }
);
```

(where `list` is the name of your variable of type `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`).

Comment: looks much better than previous examples - let me do it inside code

Comment: unfortunately, doesn't work

Comment: i was update question with you code... can u change your snippet?

Comment: @user170317: It looks like it *did* work: the maps end up in sorted order by `name`. First `Office O`, then `Test Text Last`, then `life:) Eng`, then `life:) Rus`, then `life:) Ukr`, then `дима куплеватскиц`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: to be sure, i was renamed one contact, but order of hash'es still same :(

Comment: @user170317: Well, sure, if you sort an already-sorted list, then its order won't change. If you want to see it in action, try sorting by `contactID` instead of `name`.

Comment: look to list now, one name there was changed and start from a - it have to be first, but first is still Office

Comment: @user170317: You seem to be confused. `O` comes *before* `a` in Unicode order. For a case-insensitive comparison, you can try `firstName1.compareToIgnoreCase(firstName2)` instead of `firstName1.compareTo(firstName2)`; but even that will not do anything particularly intelligent when you mix different scripts (e.g. Latin and Cyrillic), as your example does.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem you are having is that a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is completely unordered. If you want to add order to the data in a HashMap, the classic solution is to use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Depending on your situation, perhaps you cannot start out using a `TreeMap`. If so, you will want to convert your `HashMap` to a `TreeMap`:

```
TreeMap treeMap = new TreeMap();
treeMap.putAll(hashMap);           // where "hashmap" was already filled
```

The resulting `TreeMap` will be ordered based upon the "keys" of your `HashMap`.

However, if you want to add order to the data in an , the classic solution is similarly to use a [TreeList](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TreeList.html).

If you want to sort an `ArrayList` of `HashMap`s using values inside your each `HashMap`, all you need to do is create a `TreeMap` and place it into a `TreeList`. If you want to sort your `ArrayList` by something other than the keys of the original `HashMap`, you have a problem and will need to rethink your choice of data structure.

Comment: Note: you'll probably want to order a copy of the original data structure, not the original itself.

Comment: Good call, I added a snippet of code for that to my response.

Comment: This is defenetely wrong answer. Please see my edited question. i Don't need to sort keys and volumes inside HashMap. i have to sort HASHMAPS inside ArrayList

Comment: Sorry, I did not gather that from your original post. I have edited your post and my answer to try to clarify the idea: you want to sort an ArrayList of HashMaps based upon a object inside the HashMaps.

Comment: @theJollySin this is correct, this is what i want, unfortunately your answer not cover my task :(

Comment: @user170317 Can you explain what you want?